# perl: copying one array to another (multi-dimensional)

Tags: perl, loops

I have a code for copying few elements of one array to another array using a for loop as shown below

```
for $count_val (0..($TOTAL_CNT_VAL-1)) {
      $me->{arr1}[$count_val]{cpu} = $me->{arr2}[$count_val];  
}
```

Is there any way that the same thing can be achieved using a single line command something like **"push"** or something similar ?

Comment: No. You could write a sub that does anything you want, but there's no clear shortcut because of the `->{cpu}` after the index.

Comment: Unless `$me->{arr1}` is previously undefined, that is. Then you could use `$me->{arr1} = [ map  { +{ cpu => $_ } } @{ $me->{arr2} } ];`

Comment: @ikegami Thanks it worked with that, can u pls post it as answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postfix `for` is a little more concise

```
$me->{arr1}[$_]{cpu} = $me->{arr2}[$_] for 0..$TOTAL_CNT_VAL-1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use 5.18.2;
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Data::Dumper;
$me->{arr1}[$_]{cpu} = @me->{arr2}[$_][0..$TOTAL_CNT_VAL-1];
```

Comment: `@me->` is wrong. `@me` is an array, not a reference.